# Postgres error could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

Tags: python, django, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

> **My GitLabCI:**

```
stages:
  - test

# jobs
test_django:
  stage: test
  image: python:3.6  # this pulls the standard python 3.6 docker image
  services:
    - postgres:9.5  # this pulls a docker image with pgsql on it
  variables:
    # env vars made available to the script below
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "false"      # set to false to reduce the debug output from the CI jobs
    POSTGRES_DB: "project_ci_test"
    POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
    DATABASE_NAME: "$POSTGRES_DB"
    DATABASE_HOST: "postgres"       # magically finds the service above
    DATABASE_USER: "postgres"
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: ""
    DJANGO_SECRET_KEY: "somerandombogusstringtokeepdjangohappyandstartingproperly"
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python3-pip wkhtmltopdf xvfb  # extra packages used for pdf rendering in the tests
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pep8 . --filename=*.py --ignore=E128,E265,E501 --repeat
  - python manage.py migrate
  - python manage.py test
```

But now i'm getting error while running migrations.

**GitlabCi Error:**

```
     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
     connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
 django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Hello, guys could you please help me. what is wrong with my settings, it was working a few month ago but not it's not working.

> **Django Database Settings:**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME', ''),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER', ''),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show how to start your postgres on your gitlab-ci

Comment: I have only that info which I added on a question, could you please let me know what is the mistake which I'm doing

Comment: So with this info, the issue is `Where the postgres sql is ?`, started with gitlab-CI everytime you run a task ? Outside Gitlab-CI ? Because for now having only `postgres` as hostname to reach, mean that it should be run inside gitab-CI and inside  docker-compose.

Comment: i also have a docker file where i have some informations:

# use base python image with python 2.7
FROM python:3.6

# add requirements.txt to the image
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# set working directory to /app/
WORKDIR /app/

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: i have no more info related to gitlabci,

Comment: The moment the task run, Postgres is not live, you won't reach something that is not live, until you build it inside Gitlab-CI or outside in a real server/vm but with another hostname

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple of hours ago and my setup is a bit different from yours but you could try connecting to postgres before running the script then export the database as the first thing within the script.
You'll have something like this:

```
 variables:
 ...

POSTGRES_DB: project_ci_test
POSTGRES_USER: postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD: somerandompassword

connect:
  image: postgres
  script:
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - psql -h "postgres" -U "$POSTGRES_USER" -d "$POSTGRES_DB" -c "SELECT 'OK' AS status;"


script:
- export DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:somerandompassword@postgres:5432/project_ci_test
  ...
```

Get official way to provide password to psql: [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/libpq-envars.html)